# Cannot fix my playAudio function - error Argument labels '(contentsOf:, error:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, avplayer, avaudioplayer

I cannot write the audioPlayer part due to an error: Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:, error:)' do not match any available overloads

I already tried to write as contentOf instead of URL or changing some brackets, but no lucky here. Can someone help?

Function below:

```
@IBAction func playAudio(sender: AnyObject) {

        if audioRecorder?.isRecording == false{
            stopButton.isEnabled = true
            recordButton.isEnabled = false

            let error : NSError?

            do {

                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioRecorder!.url, error: error)

            audioPlayer?.delegate = self as? AVAudioPlayerDelegate

            if let err = error{
                print("audioPlayer error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            }else{
                audioPlayer?.play()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please add example this path value `audioRecorder`

Comment: I rewrote as below, but still get the same error:

Comment: Where should I add the path value?

Comment: please add value of  `audioRecorder` in your question :)

Comment: var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

Comment: check this document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer#topics
topins `init(contentsOf: URL)`

Answer (score 0):

The correct AVAudioPlayer class init is:

```
init(contentsOf: URL)
```

Check how to implement a do catch block, your code become:

```
do {
   audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: YourURL)
   audioPlayer?.delegate = self
   audioPlayer?.play()
} catch let error {
   print("audioPlayer error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works now

Comment: You are welcome ;) if you find this kind of error check always the documentation. You can mark my answer as accepted. Thanks